# XSLT/XPath : excluding nodes from what was selected

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to select a list of nodes that meets a certain criteria and after processing those nodes, I would like to select the remaining ones. How can I do it in XSLT and XPath.

Below is the scenario, I have this xml

```
<books>
<book name="Basic XML">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic XML">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic XSLT">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic XSLT">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic Java">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic Java">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Web Service">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="C Programming">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
</books>
```

1. Select all the `<book>` nodes with `<type>` of "Tutorial", below is the output

```
<books>
<book name="Basic XML">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>   
<book name="Basic XSLT">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="Basic Java">
    <type>Tutorial</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
</books>
```

2. Then select the other `<book>` nodes do not have a `<type>` of "Tutorial" and are not of the same `@name` as of those are selected in #1, the output is only :

```
<books>
<book name="Web Service">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
<book name="C Programming">
    <type>Educational</type>
    <grouping>A</grouping>
</book>
</books>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[type='Tutorial']"/>
```

For the second query:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/books/book[type!='Tutorial']"/>
```

Then you would need the appropriate templates to handle them:

```
<xsl:template match="/books/book[type='Tutorial']">
   Do Something...
</xsl:template>
```

and the final piece would be to check whether the current node also has a tutorial node

```
<xsl:template match="/books/book[type!='Tutorial']">
   <xsl:variable name="bookname">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:if test="count('/books/book[@name=$bookname and type='Tutorial']')=0">
      Do Something...
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vTutBooks" select="book[type = 'Tutorial']"/>
  <books>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vTutBooks"/>
  </books>

  <books>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "book[not(type = 'Tutorial')
       and
         not(@name = $vTutBooks/@name)
        ]"/>
  </books>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<books>
    <book name="Basic XML">
        <type>Educational</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Basic XML">
        <type>Tutorial</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Basic XSLT">
        <type>Educational</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Basic XSLT">
        <type>Tutorial</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Basic Java">
        <type>Educational</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Basic Java">
        <type>Tutorial</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="Web Service">
        <type>Educational</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
    <book name="C Programming">
        <type>Educational</type>
        <grouping>A</grouping>
    </book>
</books>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<books>
   <book name="Basic XML">
      <type>Tutorial</type>
      <grouping>A</grouping>
   </book>
   <book name="Basic XSLT">
      <type>Tutorial</type>
      <grouping>A</grouping>
   </book>
   <book name="Basic Java">
      <type>Tutorial</type>
      <grouping>A</grouping>
   </book>
</books>
<books>
   <book name="Web Service">
      <type>Educational</type>
      <grouping>A</grouping>
   </book>
   <book name="C Programming">
      <type>Educational</type>
      <grouping>A</grouping>
   </book>
</books>
```